# Javascript toString trick in adding function. How does it work?

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain to me how the toString trick works in the following example. The function adds all the arguments being passed for each call so `add(1)(2)(3);` equals 6.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ag8S/)

```
function add(a) {
  var sum = a;
    return function self(a) {
      sum += a;
      self.toString = function () {
          return sum;
      }
      return self;
  }
}

console.log(add(1)(2)(3));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function is a chain function, you need to return a function to be chained which then returns itself.

However, you also need a meaningful way to get its result.

In jQuery, for example, you might see `.get()` used to extract results from a chained operation. This is much the same, using `.toString()` to mean "if you're putting me somewhere a string is expected, return the result".

Answer (score 1):

It is returning itself which is a function. The `self` function also closes around `sum`. Then `console.log` is using the overridden `toString`.

Basically, this is happening

```
var a = add(1); //a is a self
var b = a(2); //b is the same self (b === a)
var c = b(3); //c is a same self (c === a && c === b)
console.log(c); // calls c.toString()
```

It isn't the `add` function getting called multiple times, it's the `self` function.

Answer (score 1):

The function `add` declares a variable `sum` and returns a function that has two purposes:

1. You can call the function with a value, which will add the value to `sum` and return the same function.
2. You can get the string value of the function, which will return the value of `sum`.

So, the value of `add(1)` is a function, where `sum` is 1.

The value of `add(1)(2)` is a function, where `sum` is 3.

The value of `add(1)(2)(3)` is a function, where `sum` is 6.

The `console.log` call will get the string value of the function, which is `sum`.

You can also write basically the same code like this, which might be somewhat easier to follow:

```
function add(a) {
    var sum = a;
    function self(a) {
        sum += a;
        return self;
    }
    self.toString = function () {
        return sum;
    };
    return self;
}

console.log(add(1)(2)(3));
```

(The difference is that `toString` is bound by the function `add`, not each time that you call the returned function. The edge case is that `console.log(add(1))` shows `1` instead of `self(a)`.)